# Story where a man can recognize any place on any planet from a single image

Tags: story-identification

I probably read this about 20 years ago, maybe a bit more.  I think it was a novel, but it may have been shorter.  No idea about the associated cover, if it was a novelette or shorter it may even have been in a magazine.

I only really recall the one character, but he was just a member of a team of (I think) three.  Each of the three, I believe there was one woman and two men, has a different special talent.  One of them might have had a talent for digging up information in the local infosphere, or maybe he/she had an esper talent; I don't really remember.

But the character I do recall had the singular talent that he could look at an image and identify exactly where it was.  He could look at the background of a portrait and positively state, just based on the visible streetscape, what planet and what city it was.  He might even have been able to give a more specific identification, like the part of the city (if not the actual street) and the local season.

It caught in my memory because it's such a relatable, but extraordinarily powerful, talent.

The team had been recruited to find someone or something, those details are long gone.  But one of the team would dig up leads, this person would identify the location; they had complementary roles and I think there was someone else doing the actual legwork of chasing the McGuffin down.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

["The Furies"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58658), by Roger Zelazny, first published in [*Amazing Stories*, June 1965](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?56476) ([available](https://archive.org/stream/Amazing_Stories_v39n06_1965-06_Gorgon776#page/n11/mode/1up) at the Internet Archive) and collected in [*Four for Tomorrow*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?14487) (1967).

A short story featuring three hunters recruited to stop a rogue soldier.

> Associate Professor Bains had mentioned the fact that Sandor Sandor had once [before age 14] studied a series of 30 random photos from all over the civilized galaxy, and that the significant data from these same photos had also been fed into the Department's L-L computer.  Sandor had named the correct planet in each case, the land mass in 29, the county or territory in 26 and he had correctly set the location itself within 50 square miles in 23 instances.  The L-L comp had named the correct planet for 27.
>
> It was not a labor of love for the computer.
>
> So it became apparent that Sandor Sandor knew just about ever damn street in the galaxy.
>
> Ten years later he knew them all.

Comment: Novelette. Available at the Internet Archive [here](https://archive.org/stream/Amazing_Stories_v39n06_1965-06_Gorgon776#page/n11/mode/1up) and [here](https://archive.org/stream/Thrilling_Science_Fiction_27_1972-10_MadMaxAU#page/n58/mode/1up).

Comment: The one line I remember from that story (was some of it in verse?) all those years ago.        "and a man who knows every damn street in the galaxy"

Comment: I'm too late. I opened this to tell you that @user14111 is, in fact, the person you're looking for ... :)

Comment: Sounds like he'd be really good at geoguessr.