# Three psychic bounty hunters hunt fugitive

Tags: story-identification

On [another site](https://www.sffchronicles.com/threads/582153/post-2541927) somebody mentioned this book but only a description of the story:

> Three men with psychic powers were hunting some fugitive across interstellar space. One could see the surroundings wherever the target was. Another knew every street, everywhere and from the description could tell where it was.

This has really intrigued me because it sounds familiar as though I've read it at some time (I think maybe in the 1970s).

I think I recall the third man was an alpha killer.

The dude on the other site said it was called *The Furies*, no author given....it is **not** the Keith Roberts book about giant wasps.

Comment: Have you got a link to the site where you saw this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [Story where a man can recognize any place on any planet from a single image](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/226844/story-where-a-man-can-recognize-any-place-on-any-planet-from-a-single-image?rq=1), Zelazny's "The Furies".

> ["The Furies"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58658), by Roger Zelazny, first published in [*Amazing Stories*, June 1965](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?56476) ([available](https://archive.org/stream/Amazing_Stories_v39n06_1965-06_Gorgon776#page/n11/mode/1up) at the Internet Archive) and collected in [*Four for Tomorrow*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?14487) (1967).
>
> A short story featuring three hunters recruited to stop a rogue soldier.

You are right about the talents:

> Associate Professor Baines had mentioned the fact that Sandor Sandor had once studied a series of thirty random photos from all over the civilized galaxy, and that the significant data from these same photos had also been fed into the Department's L-L computer. Sandor had named the correct planet in each case, the land mass in 29, the county or territory in twenty-six, and he had correctly set the location itself within fifty square miles in twenty-three instances. The L-L comp had named the correct planet for twenty-seven.
>
> It was not a labor of love for the computer.
>
> So it became apparent that Sandor Sandor knew just about every damn street in the galaxy.
>
> Ten years later he knew them all.

....

> The reason for [Benedict's] wealth is because his power extended to inanimate objects as well. Minerals were rare on Kjum, the watery world. If anyone brought him a sample he could hold it and weep and tell them where to dig to hit the main lode.
>
> From one fish caught in the vast seas of Kjum, he could chart the course of a school of fish.
>
> Weeping, he could touch a native rad-pearl necklace and divine the location of the native's rad-pearl bed.
>
> Local insurance associations and loan companies kept Benedict Files-the pen a man had used to sign his contract, his snubbed-out cigarette butt, a plastex hanky with which he had mopped his brow, an object left in security, the remains of a biopsy or blood test-so that Benedick could use his power against those who renege on these companies and flee, on those who break their laws.

....

> Lynx Links looked like a beachball with a beard, a fat patriarch with an eyepatch, a man who loved good food and drink, simple clothing, and the company of simple people; he was a man who smiled often and whose voice was soft and melodic.
>
> In his earlier years he had chalked up the most impressive kill-record of any agent ever employed by Interstel Central Intelligence. Forty-eight men and seventeen malicious alien life-forms had the Lynx dispatched during his fifty-year tenure as a field agent. He was one of the three men in the galaxy to have lived through half a century's employment with ICI. He lived comfortably on his government pension despite three wives and a horde of grandchildren; he was recalled occasionally as a consultant; and he did some part-time missionary work on the side. He believed that all life was one and that all men were brothers, and that love rather than hate or fear should rule the affairs of men. He had even killed with love, he often remarked at Tranquility Session, respecting and revering the person and, the spirit of the man who had been marked for death.

FWIW, I remembered seeing on the site before, and searched for `site:scifi.stackexchange.com "knows * street"`

Comment: Definitely my thought too.  (I wonder why I thought of that? :D)